# jQuery UI DatePicker defaults to the last date in the date range

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The datepicker defaults to the max date even though a default date has been provided. The following code sets the min, max & defaultDate for the date picker. However, when displayed the textbox and the default date in the date picker is set to the max date.

Is this is a datepicker bug?

```
  var from = new Date(parseInt(dict["from"].substr(6)));
  var to = new Date(parseInt(dict["to"].substr(6)));
  $("#PlanDate").datepicker('option', {
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                defaultDate: $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", from),
                minDate: from,
                maxDate: to
            });
```

Comment: Is $.datepicker.formatDate() returning what you are expecting?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle Yes, it is returning the expected date in the right format.

Comment: And you double checked that to and from aren't accidentally swapped somehow? Other than that, I'm stumped.